# OAuth2: Prevent abuse of access tokens by legitimate resource server

Tags: oauth-2.0

Considering a multi-service setup, where a single authorization server (AS) manage the access to multiple resource server (RS), in this example RS1 and RS2.

If we have one access token for both RS and we sending an access token to RS1 than RS1 would be able to make calls with this access token to RS2. This is a security threat I would like to avoid especially in an environment where not every resource server is trustworthy.

The [rfc6819](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819) mention this threat and the solution:

> Authorization servers in multi-service environments may consider
> issuing tokens with different content to different resource servers
> and to explicitly indicate in the token the target server to which a
> token is intended to be sent.

However, I am new to OAuth2 and struggling in understanding HOW to implement this. I understand that there is the `scope` and the `audience` concept in OAuth2, but I don't see how the different authorization flows issues different access tokens for different resource servers.

For the sake of simplicity we take the [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)

The client performs a login to acquire an refresh token and an access token

```
GET /token
 ?grant_type=password
 &username=user
 &password=pass
 &scope=rs1 rs2
```

The AS respond:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache

{
  "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
  "token_type":"bearer",
  "expires_in":3600,
  "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA",
}
```

The `access_token` parameter here is REQUIRED as stated by the RFC. But what access token should it be? One for RS1 or one for RS2? How to acquire the other needed access tokens? Should I utilize the refresh token?

Maybe the RFC does not considers this use case. Are there any best or common practices how to prevent leaking an access token from one RS to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From OAUth specificaiton perspective, you must use `scope` to define the intended audience of access tokens. This is defined as follow ([reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3)),

> The authorization and token endpoints allow the client to specify the
> scope of the access request using the "scope" request parameter.  In
> turn, the authorization server uses the "scope" response parameter to
> inform the client of the scope of the access token issued.

When you define this in your authorization request (or in token request depending on the flow used). Once this is done, authorization server must issue access token with requested scope.

Now when you validate the access token from resource server (or client depending on the scenario) you must validate the scope value. For this you have two options.

First is to use `token introspection` endpoint defined by [rfc7662](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662). In the introspection endpoint, you can obtain scope values of the access token.

Second option comes with self contain access tokens. When authorization server issue JWT structured access tokens, they are identified as self contained access tokens. JWT can include the `scope` value in its claims so that when resource server receive the token, it can check this value.

Finally, you claim,

> If we have one access token for both RS and we sending an access token to RS1 than RS1 would be able to make calls with this access token to RS2

This should never happen when you follow right validation steps.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask: Should I perform an authorization request per scope then, to obtain the different access tokens? In this case I have to manage different refresh tokens (one token per scope) and the user must given consent to every scope? Or is it ok to perform one authorization request for all scopes and obtain a refresh token for all scopes and then use this refresh token in different token requests to obtain the different access token?

Comment: @Timo do not confuse the usage of refresh token. Refresh token is used to renew the access token. If your client require to consume two resources (R1 and R2) then you can obtain two access tokens for them. For this you might need to send two authorization requests. But on the other hand, you may also get one access token which can use against R1 and R2. In this case you must trust R1 and R2 for not misusing access token at their end. All of this depends on your

Comment: @Time also if my comment is bit confusing, the refresh token is issued along with the access token. When you renew the access token, you will get an access token with the same scope carried in original authorization request. I do not recommend to use the refresh token to alter scope values of access token. Rather think about obtaining multiple access tokens or use access tokens with multiple scopes. Hope this is clear ?

Comment: Hi. I understand it know :) Thank you for your help :)